# Vuetify stepper Load a component based on the state

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify stepper. There 4 steps and each step has it's own component. Each component fires an axios call on mounted. What I am trying to achieve is mount a component based on the step of the stepper. How would i create this?

```
<template>

    <v-stepper v-model="state"
               vertical
               non-linear>

        <v-stepper-step editable :complete="state > 1"
                        step="1">
            General
        </v-stepper-step>

        <v-stepper-content step="1">
            <generalBooks :url="url"
                          />
            <v-btn color="primary" @click="state = 2">Continue</v-btn>
            <v-btn text>Cancel</v-btn>
        </v-stepper-content>

....

<template>

<script>
  export default{
    data: () => ({ state: 1 })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is put v-if on the component tag to check `state` is equal components step

```
<v-stepper-content step="1">
  <generalBooks v-if="state >= 1" :url="url" />
```

But this way when client back to the lower steps the component rerender again, another way is `watch` over `state` to check step and save loaded components name in an array and recheck array with current component name in in v-if or
save highest State client watched so componenet already loaded

```
<v-stepper-content step="1">
  <generalBooks v-if="highestState >= 1" :url="url" />
```

```
data(){
  state: 1,
  highestState: 1,
},
watch: {
  state(val){
    if(val > this.highestState) this.highestState = val;
  },
}
```